# Firefox always caches when Last-Modified header is set

Tags: firefox, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control, if-modified-since

I am trying to implement browser caching using `If-Modified-Since` headers in my Flask application. During normal navigation (as in, clicking a link, rather than a hard refresh), Firefox caches the page rather than making the HTTP request. This means that Firefox is not sending the `If-Modified-Since` header, and thus the server is not able to return an updated version of the page.

Attached is a screenshot of my console. Of note:

1. The response is marked as "cached"
2. The cached response is saying that my server is returning an If-Modified-Since header. However, it is returning the *previous* value of that header. If Firefox were to actually make the HTTP request, the server would return with an updated timestamp.

Is this typical behavior? Should I be using cache headers differently? How can I achieve the intended behavior, whereby the browser only caches if the server confirms that the content has not been updated? (Firefox 81.0.2 on OSX).

[image: Firefox console output]

Comment: See the linked question; `Cache-Control: no-cache`, and supporting `If-Modified-Since`, is what you want here.

Comment: Update: I have discovered that I can use `cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate` which seems to do the "right thing" in terms of asking the browser to validate each request.